# datepicker common options but different altField altFormat

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Using jquery-ui datepicker

I would like to use altField and altFormat to 2 datepickers on the same page but I can't figure out how to add these 2 options which are specific to each datepicker along with my common set of options.

Code sample below. #dt1 does not work, but #dt2 works. How can I get #dt1 to work while using the datepickerOpts?

```
  var datepickerOpts = {
   minDate: -2,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  };
  $('#dt1').datepicker(datepickerOpts,
  {altField: '#alt1',
   altFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
  });
  $('#dt2').datepicker({
   minDate: -2,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
   altField: '#alt2',
   altFormat: '@'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed in altField and altFormat as one array option in #dt1, but you did put them as 2 different options in #dt2 (which is the right way). What you have to do is make a copy of the opts(in case you add new elements in the future) for dt1 and dt2, append the altField altFormat as part of the datepickerOpts, and pass them as the only option to datepicker initialization.